# Required Knowledge About the debugging of android source code from android studio

Tags: android, debugging

I tried many times to debug my source code via breakpoint. 
i am following below mention steps:

1).First, I am running my app at debug mode(Click the icon place near by run).

2).Second, Use a breakpoint in between lines of code.

3).Follow the stepin process.

But No Cursor move from this place.

please help me, I am new to learn android Native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the below steps to debug your app.
If you run your app in debug mode(that is by clicking the 'Debug App' icon that appears to the right of 'Run' icon), you have to set the breakpoints before you enter into the appropriate screen.

For example, if you debug your main screen of the app, you need to set the breakpoints first and then run the app in debug mode. Otherwise, you run the app in debug mode and set the breakpoints before navigating to the appropriate screen.

**Simply saying setting breakpoint first is the must before running your appropriate code to debug.**

The step into process allows you to get into the method code block, if any exists, in the statement attached to the breakpoint.

In order to move step by step, you must use the step over process. The step over icon appears near to the step into icon in the Debug window.